# Notify EditContext that field has changed for Blazor validation

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to understand the inner workings of Blazor (and eventually write some middleware).  I have a [fiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/niol9ihi) that binds three different fields in three different ways:

[image: fiddle]

- The FirstName field is bound to an InputText works as expected and displays the validation message when clearing the box and focus changes.
- The MiddleName field is bound to a regular input and does not work "as expected" and displays no validation message when it is cleared and focus changes.  By going thru the Blazor source, I've identified that EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged is a concern of the control itself (InputBase).

  - Worth noting that the message IS displayed if you submit the form which I would like to understand the lifecycle involved.
- The LastName field is also bound to a regular input, but does a bit of hackery to raise EditContext.OnFieldChanged and trigger the validation to work.  **Is there a better way to do this for onchange?  How does the submit manage to raise the validation message?**  There is a lot of reference capture, expressions, reflection, and use of the "internal use only" CreateBinder method.

Below is the code for the fiddle for easier reference:

```
@page "/"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@using System.Linq.Expressions;
@using System.Reflection;
@implements IHasEditContext;

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<EditForm EditContext="this.EditContextRef">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>
    <div class="form-group">
        <InputText @bind-Value="@this.FirstName" class="form-control" />
        <ValidationMessage For="() => this.FirstName"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input @bind-value="@this.MiddleName" class="form-control" />
        <ValidationMessage For="() => this.MiddleName"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input value="@this.LastName" class="form-control" @onchange="(CreateBinder2(this, () => this.LastName,  this.LastName))" />
        <ValidationMessage For="() => this.LastName"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>


    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</EditForm>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        EditContextRef = new EditContext(this);
    }

    //BasicFormValidator Form1Validator = new BasicFormValidator();
    [Required]
    public String FirstName { get; set; } = "delete me and change focus to cause validation";
    [Required]
    public String MiddleName { get; set; } = "delete me and change focus - no validation";
    [Required]
    public String LastName { get; set; } = "delete me and change focus - validation but manually calling NotifyFieldChanged";

    public EditContext EditContextRef { get; set; }

    public static EventCallback<ChangeEventArgs> CreateBinder2(
        IHasEditContext receiver,
        Expression<Func<string?>> propExpression,
        string existingValue,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo? culture = null)
    {
        var fieldIdentifier = FieldIdentifier.Create(propExpression);
        Action<String> valueSetter = (string v) =>
        {
            PropertyInfo prop = fieldIdentifier.Model.GetType().GetProperty(fieldIdentifier.FieldName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            prop.SetValue(fieldIdentifier.Model, v);
            receiver.EditContextRef.NotifyFieldChanged(fieldIdentifier);
        };

        return EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string>(receiver, valueSetter, existingValue, culture);
    }


}
```

Comment: This might help ... https://chrissainty.com/creating-bespoke-input-components-for-blazor-from-scratch/

Comment: @NeilW that definitely would have helped in creating the example.  However, I am looking to NOT create controls and just control the binding.  I still want to be able to use existing control libraries, but manipulate the way they get data from the Model.  In MVC this could be accomplished with ModelBinderProviders, MetadataProviders, and ValidatorProviders, but that layer doesn't seem to exist here.  I'm ok with the CreateBinder2 method I've created, but I am trying to better understand the submit case and see if there are any refinements that can be made.

Comment: Without knowing what an example "existing control" looks like, I don't think there's a good answer to your question.  Generally speaking you will need some form of wrapper component to wire data into your control and interface with Blazor EditForm/EditContext infratructure.  Hacking it in will almost certain have side effects you haven't yet discovered.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I will take an answer for the generic <input> I am using in the example.  NielW's example more or less at least help me feel like my solution is less hackey then I thought (more or less doing the same thing with editcontext, and expression, and Notification).  So while I'm hoping for a more direct or straight forward method to my CreateBinder2, I can settle with it.  But i still don't understand how the submit did manage to raise NotifyFieldChanged.

Comment: @b_levitt.  I've added an answer below.  Not enough space in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

> But i still don't understand how the submit did manage to raise NotifyFieldChanged

It didn't. When you Submit the EditForm then EditContext.Validate() is called and validates *all* fields (properties) in the Model.

I don't know the exact inner workings of Validate() but you can add this to the fiddle:

```
 <input type="button" value="Check" @onclick="ValidateThis" />
```

and

```
void ValidateThis()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before " + string.Join(",", EditContextRef.GetValidationMessages()));
    EditContextRef.Validate();
    Console.WriteLine("After  " + string.Join(",", EditContextRef.GetValidationMessages()));
}
```

The "After" writeline will include MiddleName if that is empty.

Comment: thank you, that at least answers that part.

Answer (score 1):

Your `EditForm` includes a Submit button, so when you click the button, `EditForm` recognises the submit action and calls it's internal `HandleSubmitAsync`.  Even if you have no handlers attached to the `EditForm`, this method calls `Validate` on the `EditContext`.  This will validate all validation attributed properties in your `model`, which in your case is the actual component (page).

There's nothing wrong with your manual `OnChange` handling and setting, as long as you have a good understanding of how `InputBase`, `EditForm` and `EditContext` work and interreact.  You're just reproducing what's wrapped up in `InputBase`.  Calling `NotifyFieldChanged` maintains the editstate on the `EditContext`.  However, be aware that this is not really a true representation of the editstate, it only maintains the state against the last edit not against the original model.

As this is a demo, using the component as the Model is Ok, but you should have a proper data class for the model (you almost certainly know this already, but as others may read this answer later, ...).

Comment: thank you for this.  Yes, technically speaking using "this" as the view model was just for simplicity in the fiddle.  And I also appreciate you calling out simplicity vs what "should" be done for other readers.  That said......

Comment: ....that said, it's worth a debate elsewhere whether or not this is bad practice.  I firmly believe in the difference between a model or business class which is likely persisted in it's entirety to a db and a "view model" which is typically represents the total state of a UI (including a ref to a formal model it is trying to maintain).   In patterns with code-behind, it is reasonable that the codebehind IS the view model and doesn't need to be split between two classes.  Like i said debatable, but you can go back as far as webforms and see the code-behind as a view model.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `<InputText>` component you can use more complex binding super easily.

For example:

```
<InputText Value="@this.MiddleName"
           ValueChanged="(string middleName) => MiddleNameChanged(middleName)"
           ValueExpression="() => this.MiddleName" />

@code 
{
    private void MiddleNameChanged(string middleName)
    {
        this.MiddleName = middleName;
        // Do whatever you want here
    }
}
```

This works across all other built in Input Components for every datatype they support. It also can be combined with async and await.

If you want to create your own Input for other datatypes I suggest to inherit from InputBase and implement your BindConverter there. Here is an example which shows you how to bind to datetime values with the InputDate component.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputDate.cs